# Is it a good approach to use a core automation framework(jar file) as opposed to creating all classes of framework yourself?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-design, test-automation-framework, testing-framework

Some teams in an organization use existing core automation frameworks(made in Java). In my case, I converted it to a jar file artifact and then used it in their Selenium project as a local library/dependency. That framework consists of all utilities like TestBase.java class, excel reader, Database helper, reporting, and logging classes. The wrapper of PageObjects, customized click, send keys method with logging statements, etc...

While I made my own Cucumber framework in Selenium/Java, Maven for dependencies, etc, I did not use the existing core automation framework and made my own few utils package which has a few classes that I need.

Is that fine? Should we use the core automation framework(as a jar file) in our scripting project? What framework approach do you use?

Answer (score 1):

- Leverage and reuse something implemented already in same company is always cost and time effective and preferred way to kick start your projects immediately
- Realistically you can ask below few questions to get best answer on your own without being biased:

  - Get whole code base to review/study and conclude whether it would serve your purpose too?
  - Can you draw points which was not meeting or close to your requirements?
  - That could be language, component they are using which you are not using in your project or you can not (prefer) to use or have strong reason to avoid it?
  - Then have cross check with other team-mates and share your thoughts and proposal why not possible to use existing work? Make it a plan by adding your observations and findings, what all and how differently implemented stuff could be lot beneficial to your project
  - Happily start implementing your own framework instead of using available one
  - Other side of the coin would be - To check all implemented methods, verification steps, locators strategy used, how they does reporting, targeted platform, components, framework are all what you could plan to implement? If yes then no point to keep reinventing the wheel again
  - Use and leverage those projects by importing JARs, make a wiki documents for further and future reference and kick start. Spend your time and energy for your project automation

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use a pre-existing core automation framework as a jar file or build your own framework depends on a variety of factors. Here are a few things to consider:

1. What are the features and functionalities provided by the pre-existing core automation framework?
2. Is the pre-existing core automation framework aligned with your organization's goals and requirements?
3. How well has the pre-existing core automation framework been tested and used in the past?
4. What is the level of support and maintenance provided for the pre-existing core automation framework?
5. Does the pre-existing core automation framework align with your development team's technical skills and knowledge?

If the pre-existing core automation framework meets your needs, using it as a jar file can save time and resources. It can also improve the consistency and reliability of your tests. On the other hand, building your own framework provides more control and customization over your testing process. It also allows your team to align the framework with the specific needs of your project.

Ultimately, the choice depends on your organization's goals and the specific needs of your project.